# How to make a field auto populate in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
Connection.Open();
    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(null, Connection);
    Command.CommandText = "Insert into [EmployeeTable] (Forename,Surname,DateofBirth,Email address,Country,Address,City,Postcode,Skill1,Skill2,Skill3,Job1,Job 2,Job3,EmployeeAvailability) Values(@forename, @surname, @dateofbirth, @emailaddress, @phonenumber, @country, @address, @city, @postcode, @skill1, @skill2, @skill3, @job1, @job2, @job3, @employeeavailability)";
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", ForenameInputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", SurnameInputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", DoBInputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailaddress", EmailInputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", CountryInputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", AddressInputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", CityInputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", PostcodeInputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill1", Skill1InputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill2", Skill2InputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill3", Skill3InputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job1", Job1InputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job2", Job2InputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job3", Job3InputBox.Text);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeavailability", EmployeeAvailablityBox.Text);
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Connection.Close();
}
```

}

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeTable] (
[EmployeeID]            INT           NOT NULL,
[Forename]              NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Surname]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[DateofBirth]         DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[Emailaddress]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Country]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Address]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[City]                  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Postcode]              NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Skill1 ]              NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Skill2]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Skill3]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Job1]                BIT           NOT NULL,
[Job2]                BIT           NOT NULL,
[Job3]                 BIT           NOT NULL,
[EmployeeAvailability] BIT           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeID] ASC)
```

);

I have created a table to store details about an employee, however i am presented with an error message when trying to save the inputs. 
The error message is as follows:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmployeeID', table 'C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\WPFAPPLICATION\WPFAPPLICATION1\EMPLOYEEDB.MDF.‌​dbo.EmployeeTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated

I assume this is because no value has been inputted into the EmployeeID field, so how can I make it so that a new employee ID is generated every time and the field is populated, assuming this is the cause of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to make the column an `IDENTITY` column:

```
[EmployeeID]   INT   IDENTITY(1,1),
```

Then the database will generate a number with each insert automatically.  This has the added benefit of guaranteeing uniqueness, which is important given that this column is also used as your primary key.  And since an `IDENTITY` is always an increasing value, being a `CLUSTERED` index will also work out pretty well.